# Extract mail from Each value in a Column in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-extraction

Create a function that evaluates the data within a cell and extracts only the email, place the value found in a new column called "Email Found".

This is the Code I'm using, it work if I use it with a single str, but it doesn't work for my DataFrame

```
import re

def extract_mail(text):
    match = re.search(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', text)
    return match
```

This is the error that appears

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SruEk.png)

Input

```
Maxwell <maxwell_hamilton557388853@nimogy.biz> Contact Info.
Julianna <julianna_davies130654969@famism.biz> Contact Info.
Janelle <janelle_cartwright528965940@bulaffy.com> Contact Info.
```

Output

```
maxwell_hamilton557388853@nimogy.biz 
julianna_davies130654969@famism.biz
janelle_cartwright528965940@bulaffy.com
```

I have to created a New Column in the dataframe called "Email Found".

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try this using the [str accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html) with `extract` method and your regex:

```
df['email'] = df['info'].str.extract('([\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+)')
df['Email Found'] = df['email'].notna()
```

output:

```
                                                info  \
0  Maxwell <maxwell_hamilton557388853@nimogy.biz>...   
1  Julianna <julianna_davies130654969@famism.biz>...   
2  Janelle <janelle_cartwright528965940@bulaffy.c...   

                                     email  Email Found  
0     maxwell_hamilton557388853@nimogy.biz         True  
1      julianna_davies130654969@famism.biz         True  
2  janelle_cartwright528965940@bulaffy.com         True
```